# Retrieving POST data with CakePHP without formhelper

Tags: php, cakephp, post

I'm trying to pass a POST variable to one of my controllers, however I'm doing this from a static page (I know, not the cleanest and most efficient way to go about things. But for the sake of learning...). How can I read that POST variable in my controller if the POST data is being sent without a FormHelper form?

I'm posting the data using jQuery ajax, so this is  without the CakePHP native "FormHelper".

Does this make sense? Let me know if I need to elaborate. I appreciate any help you can provide :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to access the data with:

```
$this->params['form']['YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME']
```

And if you follow the naming convention used by the FormHelper and name your input field like `data[ModelName][FieldName]`, then you can access the data as usual with:

```
$this->data['ModelName']['FieldName']
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget Cake is just PHP.

```
class BazController extends AppController {

    function foo() {
        $foo = $_POST['bar'];
        $this->set('foobar', $foo);
    }

}
```

is perfectly valid. But I would do as @dhofstet suggests as it's much more "cakey".

Answer (score 2):

You should able to access form post data with:

**For CakePHP 2.x**

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    pr($this->request->data);
}
```

**For CakePHP 3.4.x**

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    pr($this->request->getData());
}
```

Please for further reference, read the manual. It's so much easier and better for yourself to figure it out by yourself.

[Documentation for CakePHP 2.x](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters)

[Documentation for CakePHP 3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-body-data)

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 2.x it is

```
$this->request->data['ModelName']['field_name'];
```

or

```
$_POST['data']['ModelName']['field_name'];
```

The first option is recommended.